# Click on button by class

Tags: javascript

```js
function clicks() {
    document.querySelector('.a-button-text').click();
}
window.onload = clicks;
```

```html
<span class="a-button">
    <span class="a-button-inner"><button class="a-button-text" type="button">Search</button>
    </span>
</span>
```

I am trying to click on the button whenever the page loads. I tried by calling it by class but it is not working for me .

Comment: The code works fine and click the button onload.

Comment: Are you getting any error in the JavaScript console?

Comment: How do you know it's not working? Clicking on the button doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, the code works fine. But what is your purpose of this? You can call directly its `onclick` function.

```js
function clicks() {
  document.querySelector('.a-button-text').click();
}

function f1() {
  console.log("Search button clicked!");
}

window.onload = clicks;
```

```html
<span class="a-button">
<span class="a-button-inner">
<button onclick="f1()" class="a-button-text" type="button">Search</button>
</span>
</span>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. If you have a question, post it as a comment instead.

Comment: @NisargShah yes, you are right. I commented too. I tried to make a working example to prove him and also tried to suggest another way!

Comment: The correct action would be to vote-to-close, not to post an answer. You have the privilege for that.

Comment: Thanks for guidance. I'll consider this in future. @NisargShah

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function(){
 // once script is loaded the function will execute
 var selectedElement = document.querySelector(".a-button-inner")
 
 // add a click event to the button (to identify that the click is invoked for the button)
 selectedElement.addEventListener("click", function(){
    alert("you clicked the button !!")
 })
 
 // invoke the click method 
 selectedElement.click();
 

})()
```

```html
<span class="a-button">
<span class="a-button-inner"><button class="a-button-text" type="button">Search</button>
</span>
</span>
```

Comment: He doesn't want an event listener, he wants to trigger a click.

Comment: Don't just post code. Explain what was wrong in the original code, and how you fixed it. Why did you change from `querySelector` to the more verbose `getElementsByClassName`?

Comment: i was just adding a message to show :) no need of that

Answer (score 0):

```js
function clickButton(){
 document.getElementsByClassName("btn")[0].click();
}

window.onload= clickButton;
```

```html
<button class="btn" onclick="alert('hello');">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works correctly.
You can check by inserting alert or console.log on each click as shown below.
Apart from this, if you are still facing the issue than try to elaborate the problem.

```
<span class="a-button">
        <span class="a-button-inner">
            <button class="a-button-text" type="button" onclick="clickFunc()">Search</button>
        </span>
    </span>


function clicks() {
        document.querySelector('.a-button-text').click();
    }
    window.onload = clicks;

   function clickFunc() {
       console.log('Button clicked');
   }
```